# Modifying my longbow to +11 and higher

Tags: dark-souls

I have a +10 Longbow, and I want to modify it to +11.

I read that I need Titanite Chunks; I have 4 of them, so I went to the blacksmith. But I can't seem to upgrade my bow.

#### Did I miss something to reinforce my longbow above +10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give the [Very Large Ember](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Very_Large_Ember) to the Blacksmith Andre of Astoria.

It is found in the New Londo Ruins, under Firelink Shrine.

It is the same process than to upgrade from +5 to +6 ; only this time, the ember is *very* large.

Comment: aaah! I love this game but also i hate it sometimes! :) so confusing! :) thanks much i will look for it

Comment: I love it too :) Technically, it's not the game itself which is confusing, since you were not supposed to know yet that you could upgrade above +10.

Comment: well... it makes sense. True

Comment: Yes, it is ironic because the devs encourage players sharing information to find secrets, but this very often leads to misinformation or misinterpretation, especially when the game just releases.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Which is not really the case anymore. And the "information sharing" is pretty limited in-game, not like anybody can tell you "Quick ! Upgrade your weapon to +15 !"

Comment: @Ealhad, Er, people don't need to use messages in the game to share information, I am talking beyond the scope of that. Remember when DkS just released and everyone thought you could spare Sif?

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Nope. I didn't have a computer at that time.

Comment: @Ealhad Ah, well, you are lucky I guess. That, amongst many others were very prominent rumors within the first month or so of DkS' release. I was personally editing the wiki and people were posting that stuff on there like it was fact. Some of that stuff takes a while to get corrected, and sometimes people are just bad at writing on a wiki, so it's easy for information to get lost along the way even after people have figured things out. In this particular instance the OP made the game more confusing for himself by looking up that you can get weapons to +15 without knowing how to do it.